# Unexpectedly Found Nil While Unwrapping an Optional Value in Collection View

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, uicollectionview

I have created a new view controller recently that has a collection view in it. I also have to other view controllers that also have collection views.

The problem I am facing is that I am trying to use the reload function for for the new collection view but it give the error: 'fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)'

My best assumption as to why it gives error is that the new collection view is set up differently than the other two (.reloadData() works fine in the other two). This is the code for the viewDidLoad on the new collection view:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //self.resultsColl.delegate = self
    //self.resultsColl.dataSource = self

    testHashAt = textFieldFHash.text!
}
```

I commented out the delegate and dataSource lines because that is the main error. In the other two view controllers I have those two functions and they work perfectly however when I use them in the new collection view I get the same error that I did with the .reloadData().

I assume that this is the reason why I cannot use the .reloadData() function. I have added collection view to the view controller as both dataSource and delegate and in class declaration:

```
class HashtagViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
```

Also just incase this is the error, this is my getData() function and below it is the cellForItemAt and numberOfItemsInSection functions and the viewWillAppear:

```
func getData() {

    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

    do {
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Task> = Task.fetchRequest()
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate.init(format: "hashtag = %@", testHashAt);
        taskTwo = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
    }

    catch {
        print("Get Data failed")
    }

    // Fetches data.
}
```

and the cellForItemAt and numberOfItemsInSection:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return taskTwo.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let taskTHash = taskTwo[indexPath.row]

    let cellHash = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "nCell", for: indexPath) as! HashCollectionViewCell


    if testHashAt == taskTHash.hashtag {
        cellHash.labelFHash.text = taskTHash.name!
    }
    else {
        print("blank cell?")
    }

    if cellHash.labelFHash.text == "" {
        print("cell is nil")
    }

    cellHash.layer.cornerRadius = 25

    return cellHash
}
```

and viewWillAppear:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    getData()
    resultsColl.reloadData()
}
```

I don't know why this collection view doesn't work with dataSource, delegate and reloadData(). How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you please show how you declare and initialize your collection view that causes the problems?

Comment: Start by finding out what line is causing the error.  Put a breakpoint on Swift errors so that execution will stop at the right place.  Otherwise look at any place you use `!` in an assignment and change it so that you test the value instead of telling the compiler to assume it's not nil.

Comment: @PhillipMills I've done that although I commented out lines to see which ones are causing issues. The lines that are causing issues is the self.resultsColl.delegate/dataSource = self lines. Also the reloadData() line causes the problem but I assume that it is interlinked with the delegate and dataSource not working.

Comment: @PhilippOtto I'm not sure what you mean, are you referring to how the items in the collection view are imported with CoreData or the general creating (drag and drop, collection view cell view controller etc.)?

Comment: @Richard: No I mean the lines where you declare and initialise the variable resultsColl. As you already stated you set it via an outlet in the interface builder. Are you 100% sure that resultsColl is set and NOT nil at the time you set the dataSource and delegate? Did you connect your outlet variable correctly to the storyboard item?

Comment: Commenting out lines isn't the same thing.  That changes large chunks of behavior.  What I suggested pinpoints the exact bug.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not creating collection view from code.. Check if you connected correct IBOutlet of your collection view in your view controller

Comment: I added a IBOulet of type collection view. Thanks for response.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue.

I am not sure as to what caused it but I deleted the declaration of the collection view in the view controller and re-added the IBOutlet and that seemed to have fixed the issue. As @PhillipMills stated it might have been that the collection view was nil when I added it and I assume that was the cause of the problem. Thanks for the help!